# Obj-C introspection: How can a method reference its own selector?

Tags: objective-c, methods, selector, introspection

I wish to write a macro, to be used within any method, which references the method's selector.  I do not wish to pass the literal name of the method. For example:

```
#define RERUN [self performSelector:{something} withObject:nil afterDelay: 0.0]
```

where the "{something}" in the above would resolve to the selector of whatever method the macro was used in.

Is there some way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`_cmd` represents the selector of the current method -- it is a hidden argument (like `self`).

if you never need arguments, or `nil` is suitable for your purpose - all you need to do is write:

```
#define RERUN [self performSelector:_cmd]
```

Comment: Your RERUN is subtly different from the original though — yours will occur right then on the current call stack, the original will schedule the call on the current run loop but not immediately call anything.

Comment: @Tommy good point (+1) -- i thought the original was odd for that reason. the difference (for those who are wondering) is that the implementation i posted will be called immediately (it may also recurse infinitely if the condition is never met and cause a stack overflow). using the `afterDelay:` variant, `self` will be retained, and the message will be enqueued in the current run loop and happen in the future.

Comment: Thanks, _cmd is exactly what I wanted.  In my case, my purpose was specifically to give the run loop some cycles and then re-call the method.

Comment: You're welcome, and `afterDelay:` was exactly what you wanted in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Methods get an implicit argument _cmd, which is the selector.